# sort alphabetically values of NSPopUpButton bind to NSArrayController

Tags: cocoa, core-data, xcode6, nsarraycontroller, nspopupbutton

I have a cocoa project where I'm using bindings. I have an NSArrayController pulling data from core data and using the NSArrayController to populate NSPopUpButton but I need to sort alphabetically the values to show in the NSPopUpButton. Any of you know I do this?. I'll really appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your controller that returns an array of sort descriptors, something like this...

```
- (NSArray*)sortDescriptorsForPopupFoo {
    // Create and return array of NSSortDescriptor
}
```

In IB, click on the controller, then go to the bindings inspector, and you can bind the method to the "Sort Descriptors" bindings for the array controller.